# css find closest item

Tags: css, selector

I have a nested structure that contains the same elements. To only target the elements within the current set I do something like this:

```
.set1 > .content > .trigger {
  background: red;
}
```

In real life this selector has much more elements. While it works, if I change the name or depth on one of the elements it will no longer work.

Is there a way to just find the `.trigger` (in this case) of the current set?

```
<div class="set set1">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="trigger"></div>
    <div class="set set2">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="trigger"></div>
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: First instance of `.trigger` or all `.trigger`?

Comment: Can you share the jquery code that you have tried??

Comment: @Swellar First instance of trigger.

Comment: @SreenathPG It's not a jQuery question. It's all about CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a style on all triggers inside the current set and then remove the style for the other triggers that comes after the first trigger.

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.set1 .trigger {
  background: red;
}

.set1 .trigger ~ .set .trigger {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="set set1">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="trigger"></div>
    <div class="set set2">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="trigger"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```